# If only 1 field out of 4 is available

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the below code on a WP site.

```
<?php
    $images = array();
    $images[] = $profile_user->banner_image_1;
    $images[] = $profile_user->banner_image_2;
    $images[] = $profile_user->banner_image_3;
    $images[] = $profile_user->banner_image_4;  

    if(!empty($images[0]) || !empty($images[1])|| !empty($images[2])||   !empty($images[3])){
?>
    <?php echo '<div class="slider2">'; ?>

    <?php foreach($images as $img): ?>
        <?php if(!empty($img)): ?>
            <div>
                <img src="
                <?php   
                    $image_id = $img;
                    $post_image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, $size='profile_banner_img' );
                    echo $post_image_data[0];
                ?>" />
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php echo '</div>'; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

What i need to do is use a "IF" or "array" statement or something that will see if only "banner_image_1" has been filled by user and display a different code.

In other words if banner_image_1 returns information but 2,3,4 dont i need remove the

```
<div class="slider2"> and the </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$images = array();

for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++) {
    if(!empty($profile_user->{"banner_image_$i"})) {
        $images[] = $profile_user->{"banner_image_$i"};
    }
}

$validPics = count($images);


if($validPics > 0) {
    if($validPics > 1) echo '<div class="slider2">';

    foreach($images as $img_id) {

        $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $img_id, $size='profile_banner_img' );

        echo '<div><img src=\"' . $img_src[0] . '" /></div>';

    }

    if($validPics > 1) echo '</div>';
}
```